# What are the solutions to $\sqrt{(xi^2)}$ and $\sqrt{(-(xi^2))}$ for $x=1$ and $x=3$?

Tags: complex-numbers

I just want to ask a simple question:

What are the solutions to $\sqrt{xi^2}$ and $\sqrt{-(xi^2)}$ for $x=1$ and $x=3$?

**Edit:** There seems to be some misunderstanding: $\sqrt{-9}=3i$. However $9$ can be written as $3^2$. The idea behind $\sqrt{-(3^2)}$ is that while $3^2 = \text{a positive number}$, $-(3^2) = \text{never a positive number}$. And thus $\sqrt{-(3^2)}$ can never be real.

Comment: Have you tried anything at all? What is giving you issues exactly?

Comment: Thank you: What is giving me issues is this one: x^2= a*a then a can have three values namely -a, a or i. I wanted to know the steps involved for solving for non-principal roots of i of these numbers.

Comment: Well, $xi^2=-x$ is a negative real number in both cases and $\sqrt{\ }$ is not defined on the nonnegative real line hence $\sqrt{xi^2}$ is a nonexistent object. Likewise, $\sqrt{-xi^2}=\sqrt{x}$ for every positive real number $x$.

Comment: Thank you very much! There is an important difference however which I would like to note. sqrt(-xi^2) is definitely not the same as sqrt(-(xi^2).

Comment: Hmmm... You do realize that this whole setting of real numbers, complex numbers, quaternions (and octonions if you like) is completely standard and mastered for several centuries now, don't you? (Ah... I was answering to a now deleted comment by the OP.)

Comment: "sqrt(-xi^2) is definitely not the same as sqrt(-(xi^2)." ??

Comment: $$(-xi^2)=-(xi^2)$$

Comment: Please stop modifying your comments after someone answered them. No, sqrt(-9) = i does not hold (and frankly I have no idea where you got the idea it does). Now, if you would excuse me...

Comment: Ok I will stop modifying my comments: Please see this last point. I know that sqrt(-9) is not i, but it is in the complex domain, and that was what I was denoting with i)

Comment: Well, St.C, if you are going to make up yoour own language, it's going to be hard to have a productive conversation with you. I'd suggest using words the same way the rest of us use them.

Comment: @DId: yes thank you. However I realized that there was a problem. sqrt(-9) = 3i right? however sqrt(-3^2)= not 3i. However you can write 9 as 3^2. So Sqrt(-(3^2)= 3i. It is just that you make sure that whatever number you get out of that square, you put a negative before it when you take it's square root. –

Answer (score 2):

First of all, your question is nonsense. Problems have solutions; equations have solutions; $\sqrt{xi^2}$ is neither a problem, nor an equation, so it makes no sense to ask for a solution of $\sqrt{xi^2}$, any more than it would make sense to ask for a solution of $17$, or a solution of blue.

But I think I know what you mean to ask. You mean to ask, how does one *evaluate*  $\sqrt{xi^2}$ and $\sqrt{-xi^2}$ for $x=1$ and for $x=3$. But to do that, you first have to know what $\sqrt{}$ means.

If $q$ is a positive real number, then there are two real numbers $r$ such that $r^2=q$. Of these two real numbers, exactly one is positive, and $\sqrt q$ is defined to be that positive number.

If $q$ is a nonzero complex number, and not a positive real number, there are two complex numbers $r$ such that $r^2=q$, but neither one of them is a positive real number. So which one do you choose to be $\sqrt q$?

The problem is, there is no choice you can make that will result in a square root function that has all the properties we associate with the square root function when it is restricted to the positive reals. Something's gotta give, and that's what you are running into with your calculations. So, think real hard about what properties you would like a square root function to have, and then think about whether it's possible for a function to have those properties.

Comment: +1. I can think of at least 4-5 pages on the site where this answer would make a tremendous amount of good.

Comment: Thank you Gerry, and that is actually the reason why I wanted to know that.The fact that square root is not well-defined for complex numbers is what I want to know. Because if not, you can use another system to define exactly that plane. Just like the complex number plane is derived from the real number plane for a square root of a negative number. That was the intention of the question.